# React-Native refresh Flatlist not working on Android

Tags: react-native

When a user presses a flatlist populated by gpsDataSource

```
this.state = {
  gpsDataSource: [
    { selected: false, title: I18n.t('Settings_precise_11f271'), code: 'precise' },
    { selected: false, title: I18n.t('Settings_approximate_b23bbf'), code: 'approximate' },
    { selected: true, title: I18n.t('Settings_off_810357'), code: 'off' },
  ],
};
```

Populated through

```
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.gpsDataSource}
          extraData={this.state.refresh}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
          <View>
              {(Platform.OS === 'android') ? 
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this._onGPSPress(item)}  background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()} >
                  <View>
                    <MenuItem
                      item={item}
                      navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    />
                  </View>
                  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                  :
                  <TouchableHighlight
                      onPress={() => this._onGPSPress(item)} 
                      underlayColor='gray'>
                      <MenuItem
                          item={item}
                          onPress={() => this._onGPSPress(item)} 
                          navigation={this.props.navigation}

                          />

                  </TouchableHighlight>
              }
          </View>
      }

          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
```

The user selects an item

```
 _onGPSPress(_click) {
    this.state.gpsDataSource.map(element => {
      if (element.code == _click.code) 
      {console.log("match");  element.selected = true; return element }
      else { console.log("no match");element.selected = false ; return element }
    });
this.setState({
  refresh: !this.state.refresh
})

//Todo: appropriate server calls
  }
```

The flatlist refreshed on iOS but not Android (incidentally, Menuitem is identical for both platforms.

How can I get the flatlist (a selected blue point is in menu item) to refresh for Android?

Comment: Did you define refresh in state? I think we should not directly change state variable by using map function as you did in _onGPSPress method